# Como fazer um script Python rodar em um horário automático?

Tags: python

Olá eu fiz um script pra envio de mensagens no Skype:

```
from skpy import Skype
sk = Skype(username, password) # connect to Skype

sk.user # you
sk.contacts # your contacts
sk.chats # your conversations

ch = sk.chats.create(["joe.4", "daisy.5"]) # new group conversation
ch = sk.contacts["joe.4"].chat # 1-to-1 conversation

ch.sendMsg(content) # plain-text message
ch.sendFile(open("song.mp3", "rb"), "song.mp3") # file upload
ch.sendContact(sk.contacts["daisy.5"]) # contact sharing

ch.getMsgs() # retrieve recent messages
```

Quero fazer com que esse código rode automaticamente todos os dias as 9:00am, alguém pode me ajudar num conselho de como fazer ou indicar uma documentação pra buscar, ja procurei muito na internet e não achei nada.

Comment: use um *task manager* do próprio sistema operacional para fazer isso, ele pode executar o seu programa no horário programado

Comment: Termos como _scheduler_ (agendador) ou _schedule_ (agendar) também ajudam a encontrar uma solução para o seu sistema operacional. No Linux por exemplo tem o `cron`. Pode incluir na busca termos como _task_, _job_ ou _script_, possivelmente um _shell script_.

Comment: Responde sim! Vou dar uma olhada pra ver como implemento isso na pratica, muito obrigado!!!